# Abstract vacation time tracker with states

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I am writing a program for vacation in a company and the time that is allowed to be in a specific holiday I used an Abstract class with an abstract method:

```
public abstract class Abstract : TimeLength
{
    public AbstractTest(string employeeCode, string employee, string typeOfHoliday, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) : base(startDate, endDate, "")
    {
        TypeOfHoliday = typeOfHoliday;
        Employee = employee;
        EmployeeCode = employeeCode;
    }
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public string Employee { get; set; }
    public string TypeOfHoliday { get; set; }

    public abstract bool HolidayValidation(string typeOfHoliday);
}
```

And I used multiple class that inherent from this abstract class like this two:

```
class MarriageVacation : Abstract
{
    public MarriageVacation(string employeeCode, string employee, string typeOfHoliday, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) : base(employeeCode, employee, typeOfHoliday, startDate, endDate)
    {
    }

    public override bool HolidayValidation(string typeOfHoliday)
    {
        if (Days() > (int)Holiday.MarriageVacation)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Marriage Vacation Can only be 5 Days");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
}


    class Bereavement : Abstract
{
      public Bereavement(string employeeCode, string employee, string typeOfHoliday, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) : base(employeeCode, employee, typeOfHoliday, startDate, endDate)
    {
    }

    public override bool HolidayValidation(string typeOfHoliday)
    {
        if (Days() > (int)Holiday.Bereavement)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Bereavement Can only be 5 Days");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

I use Enum for holidays and in the main I want to register this based on the users choice like this:

```
List<Abstract> holiday = new List<Abstract>();
if(CmbTypeHolidays.Text == Holiday.Bereavement.ToString())
    {
        var holid = new Bereavement(CmbEmpHolidays.Text.Split('-')[0], CmbEmpHolidays.Text.Split('-')[1], CmbTypeHolidays.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(StartDateHolidays.Value), Convert.ToDateTime(EndDateHolidays.Value));

        if (holid.HolidayValidation(CmbTypeHolidays.Text))
        {
            holiday.Add(holid);
            var bindingList = new BindingList<Abstract>(holiday);
            dataGridHolidays.DataSource = bindingList;
            controlPanelHolidays.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    else if (CmbTypeHolidays.Text == Holiday.MarriageVacation.ToString())
    {
        var holid = new MarriageVacation(CmbEmpHolidays.Text.Split('-')[0], CmbEmpHolidays.Text.Split('-')[1], CmbTypeHolidays.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(StartDateHolidays.Value), Convert.ToDateTime(EndDateHolidays.Value));

        if (holid.HolidayValidation(CmbTypeHolidays.Text))
        {
            holiday.Add(holid);
            var bindingList = new BindingList<Abstract>(holiday);
            dataGridHolidays.DataSource = bindingList;
            controlPanelHolidays.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

I wanted to know a better way to implement this solution or just to change the code that inserts data to the abstract List.

The timelength class:

```
public class TimeLength : BaseEntity
{

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    private string _TimeLengthCal { get; set ; }

    public string TimeLenghtCal
    {
        get { return _TimeLengthCal; }
    }
    public TimeLength(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {

        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;

        int time = (EndDate - StartDate).Days;

        var months = time / 30;
        var days = time % 30;

        var total = $"{months} Month and {days} Days";
        _TimeLengthCal = total;
    }
    public TimeLength(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate , string change = "")
    {
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
        _TimeLengthCal = Days().ToString();
    }
    public int Days()
    {
        List<DateTime> holidayslist = new List<DateTime>();
        holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2020, 1, 1));
        holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2020, 1, 2));
        holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2020, 1, 7));
        holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2020, 2, 17));
        holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2020, 4, 9));
        holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2020, 4, 13));
        holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2020, 4, 20));
        holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2020, 5, 1));
        holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2020, 5, 9));
        holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2020, 5, 11));
        holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2020, 5, 24));
        holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2020, 5, 25));
        holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2020, 7, 31));
        holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2020, 11, 28));
        holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2020, 12, 25));

        int time = (EndDate - StartDate).Days;
        int total = time;
        for (DateTime date = StartDate; date <= EndDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || holidayslist != null && holidayslist.Contains(date.Date))
                total -= 1;
        }

        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please edit your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your code in question by placing the real code. Just copy it directly from your ide.

Comment: I've forced your edit, but please log-in with the original account when making edits to your posts next time. For now, you may want to [Contact](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/contact) the site to request a merger of your accounts.

Comment: After doing what @Mast mentioned, you still need to place the original code in ther. Currently your `abstract class Abstract` wouldn't even compile.